# Azure Application Password

Tags: azure

I know that in order to login to phpMyAdmin through Azure VM with PuTTY you have to get the application password from the Boot Diagnostics. I did this perfectly fine last week, the password was on around line 928 and have # all around it so it stood out.

This week when trying to complete an assignment I went back to get my password form the Boot Diagns and it only goes to line 700ish and has no password in it. I've cleared my cache and restarted & redeployed the VM.

Does anyone know how else to get the password?

Comment: What, exactly, are you referring to? What file? What line?

Comment: The Boot Diagnostics file, where the application password is supposed to be randomly generated when the VM starts running and is supposed to be logged. Typically it is there, around line 900 in the Boot Diagnostics file, but it only loads to 700 and has no password and I don't know how else to get it.